# How to find jar and its maven gav by class name or jar name

Tags: java, maven, jar

I need to know ApplicationContext belongs to which JAR meanwhile its maven gav(I want it in some spring jar). Is there any generalized way of searching Jar to which a particular class belongs to. I find http://www.findjar.com can search the jar but not the maven gav, what about http://www.findmaven.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AdvancedSearch](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) on http://search.maven.org/

For a class name like ApplicationContext, you'll get many results, so you might want to limit your query by groupId. For example, you could [search](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3aorg.springframework%20c%3aApplicationContext) for: `g:org.springframework c:ApplicationContext`