# How can I find the Maven dependency that is responsible for a specific class in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, class, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

In IntelliJ I am trying to retrieve the Maven dependency that is responsible of providing a specific class (or an entire JAR).

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726093/104891

Comment: @CrazyCoder What if we use an internal Maven Repository where we can't search from an UI?

Comment: Use https://github.com/javalite/jar-explorer or a shell script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1500307/104891.

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo Which internal Maven Repository cannot be searched through UI? Nexus and Artifactory offer UIs.

Comment: @JFMeier I expressed myself wrong. We use Nexus but it does't support Class Name search but only Artifact search.
So no way to do that from IntelliJ or Nexus?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It should work. I was looking for something in the IDE but if there is no other way to do that...

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo Nexus 2.x supports classname search. I don't know whether this was reimplemented in Nexus 3.x

Comment: @JFMeier "There is no support for class name search in Nexus 3."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865483/classname-search-in-nexus-3

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about dependencies which aren't coming from maven central you can't use the [advanced search feature](https://search.maven.org/) on central search [as has been suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726093/9705485) and you indicate in your comments that your nexus also doesn't support searching by class name. Another option is that [IntelliJ can tell you where a class file used in your project comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173501/9705485) using the feature to open a class. This is [`⌘O` on a mac](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html). In IntelliJ 2017.1 it looks like:

[image]